# ionic capacitor run android failed

Tags: java, android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

ionic capacitor run android failed when running build gradle.
[gradle failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVEZw.png)

'* What went wrong:
Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321'

the gradle failed because he looking for JAVA_HOME in 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321' but this directory doesn't exist.

but my JAVA_HOME path is 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202'
[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfxvg.png)

I tried to reinstall java and delete the android directory without any success.

I tried to put JAVA_HOME dir in 'gradle.properties' but still the 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321' overwritten that.

When I run from the android studio it works, just from 'ionic cap run android' not working.

Comment: install Java 11.

Comment: I suppose `ionic build android` returns the same error, doesn't it? [link to similar question w/o accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186938/java-home-to-work-with-ionic#29306532)

Comment: with java 11 is the same problem.
`ionic build android` works fine for me

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? Currently facing the same issue

Comment: I found a solution to the problem, just take a look at [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668276/ionic-gradle-using-old-java-home-value/72670664#72670664).

Comment: Thank you. My solution was to change the name of the java_home folder to the name the gradle want

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

1. Set the right `$JAVA_HOME` path in `.bashrc`
2. go to `$HOME` directory and delete `.gradle` folder.
3. re-gradle your project