# Ionic Gradle using old Java_Home value

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code, ionic-framework, capacitor

I created a project with ionic and angular. Now i wanted to live debug the application in android studio.

At first the newest version of Java was installed on my machine. However running the `ionic capacitor run android` command always gave me a weird gradle error. So i googled and found a lot of people saying the java version is the problem. So i installed Java 8, removed the other version from my machine and set JAVA_HOME to the new location. So far so good.

After restarting my machine and running the `ionic capacitor run android` command again i got following error:

```
? Which device would you like to target? Pixel 3 API 30 (emulator) (Pixel_3_API_30)
> ng.cmd run app:build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files                                                     | Names                     |  Raw Size
vendor.js                                                               | vendor                    |   5.84 MB | 
polyfills.js                                                            | polyfills                 | 307.63 kB | 
styles.css                                                              | styles                    |  37.80 kB | 
main.js                                                                 | main                      |  21.51 kB | 
runtime.js                                                              | runtime                   |  13.96 kB | 

                                                                        | Initial Total             |   6.21 MB

Lazy Chunk Files                                                        | Names                     |  Raw Size
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_swiper_bundle-28080340_js.js           | swiper-bundle-28080340-js | 200.26 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-datetime_3_entry_js.js             | -                         | 140.67 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-item_8_entry_js.js                 | -                         |  93.93 kB | 
polyfills-core-js.js                                                    | polyfills-core-js         |  92.34 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-app_8_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  76.45 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-modal_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  65.33 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-slide_2_entry_js.js                | -                         |  59.81 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-popover_entry_js.js                | -                         |  57.79 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-refresher_2_entry_js.js            | -                         |  51.26 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-alert_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  47.40 kB | 
common.js                                                               | common                    |  43.41 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-segment_2_entry_js.js              | -                         |  40.65 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-menu_3_entry_js.js                 | -                         |  39.25 kB | 
default-src_app_core_data_game-data_service_ts.js                       | features-home-home-module |  37.95 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-nav_2_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  35.49 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-searchbar_entry_js.js              | -                         |  34.13 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-item-option_3_entry_js.js          | -                         |  34.12 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-button_2_entry_js.js               | -                         |  33.88 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-route_4_entry_js.js                | -                         |  32.66 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-select_3_entry_js.js               | -                         |  31.69 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-action-sheet_entry_js.js           | -                         |  30.41 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-range_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  29.04 kB | 
src_app_features_game_game_module_ts.js                                 | features-game-game-module |  27.76 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-fab_3_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  27.11 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-accordion_2_entry_js.js            | -                         |  27.08 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-tab-bar_2_entry_js.js              | -                         |  24.02 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-toast_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  23.52 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-input_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  22.73 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-breadcrumb_2_entry_js.js           | -                         |  22.20 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-progress-bar_entry_js.js           | -                         |  21.98 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-picker-internal_entry_js.js        | -                         |  21.46 kB | 
polyfills-dom.js                                                        | polyfills-dom             |  19.42 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-virtual-scroll_entry_js.js         | -                         |  19.28 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-textarea_entry_js.js               | -                         |  19.28 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-toggle_entry_js.js                 | -                         |  17.80 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-back-button_entry_js.js            | -                         |  17.25 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_input-shims-4295668e_js.js             | input-shims-4295668e-js   |  17.06 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-radio_2_entry_js.js                | -                         |  16.89 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-col_3_entry_js.js                  | -                         |  15.80 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-card_5_entry_js.js                 | -                         |  15.63 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-loading_entry_js.js                | -                         |  15.56 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-infinite-scroll_2_entry_js.js      | -                         |  14.09 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-picker-column-internal_entry_js.js | -                         |  13.49 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-reorder_2_entry_js.js              | -                         |  13.26 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-checkbox_entry_js.js               | -                         |  11.45 kB | 
src_app_features_home_home_module_ts.js                                 | features-home-home-module |  10.31 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-split-pane_entry_js.js             | -                         |  10.08 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-chip_entry_js.js                   | -                         |   9.85 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-tab_2_entry_js.js                  | -                         |   9.60 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-spinner_entry_js.js                | -                         |   8.22 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-ripple-effect_entry_js.js          | -                         |   6.61 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_tap-click-89bcc7cc_js.js               | tap-click-89bcc7cc-js     |   5.91 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-avatar_3_entry_js.js               | -                         |   5.83 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-img_entry_js.js                    | -                         |   4.54 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-backdrop_entry_js.js               | -                         |   3.47 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_status-tap-e9e23d4e_js.js              | status-tap-e9e23d4e-js    |   2.86 kB | 
node_modules_capacitor_share_dist_esm_web_js.js                         | web                       |   1.94 kB | 
node_modules_ionic_core_dist_esm_ion-text_entry_js.js                   | -                         |   1.76 kB | 

Build at: 2022-06-18T09:32:04.572Z - Hash: 4ca02a5c6d11ecb3 - Time: 5858ms
> capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_3_API_30
[capacitor] √ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 1.52s
[capacitor] √ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.40ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
[capacitor]        phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.0
[capacitor] √ copy android in 1.60s
[capacitor] √ Updating Android plugins in 9.35ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 5 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@1.1.1
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@1.1.4
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@1.2.2
[capacitor]        @capacitor/share@1.1.2
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.8
[capacitor] [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
[capacitor]        phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.0
[capacitor] √ update android in 98.85ms
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] 
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

        capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_3_API_30 exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Which comes down to:
`Supplied javaHome must be a valid directory. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.1.1`

However, the mentioned JAVA_HOME variable is the old location, i already updated JAVA_HOME to the current installation of JAVA 8.

So i tried a few things.

- Set JAVA_HOME in VS Code Settings
- [Cleaned Windows and VS Code Cache](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-clear-cache-on-windows-10/#b) and restarted my machine
- Run the ionic capacitor run android in a Command Prompt Window
- Reinstalled VS Code
- Reinstalled Ionic
- Deleted the android folder in my ionic project and run the `ionic capacitor run android` command again
- Uninstalled Java
- [Deleted gradle cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/7937665)

But nothing worked, i always get the same error with the old JAVA_HOME variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of try and error i found somewhat of a solution.

I had to delete the `.gradle` folder under `C:\Users\MyUser\.gradle`. After that i executed the command and a new folder was created, which used the new `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: what's the equivalent for ubuntu? I can't see .gradle

Answer (score 1):

for osx 13.1 (m1): `rm -r ~/.gradle`